# Windows Installer won't boot from USB drive on Intel D525MW

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios, usb-flash-drive

I try to install Windows 10 on a rather old system.

- Mainboard is a Intel Atom Desktop board (D525MW) with a BIOS rev. from 2013.
- CPU is Intel Atom D525. [Intel spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/products/49490/Intel-Atom-Processor-D525-1M-Cache-1-80-GHz-) If I read that correctly it's a 64bit architecture.
- USB Stick containing the image is a PNY 64 GiB (USB 3.0) stick
- Win 10 image is: *Win10_1809Oct_German_x64.iso* directly downloaded from MS (latest 64bit ISO in German)
- I wrote the stick by doing `dd bs=4M if=Win10_1809Oct_German_x64.iso of=/dev/sdc`
- I also tried partitioning the USB stick and writing to the first primary partition
- I also tried using a 32bit Image
- bios option „boot from USB“ was enabled

The outcome is, my BIOS won't boot from the USB stick claiming „No boot device has been detected, please press any key to reboot!" The operation light of the stick flickers at power on, so the USB-port might be working, but it shows no activity, when the time comes where I assume the boot device must be selected.

(I have built in the any key, very cumbersome, took me a week or more, so I can reboot at least)

What could be the hindrace to boot from the USB stick? Do I have to assume, that the stick is too big/new to boot from? Is my BIOS/Board broken? Are there additional settings in BIOS setup which I have to take care of?

Comment: You don't indicate what processor you have.  I suspect your problem is your attempting to install a 64-bit OS on a motherboard that has a 32-Bit UEFI kernel.  Edit your question and provide the necessary information to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I added what I could find about the CPU.

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB key?

Comment: @music2myear I wrote it directly to the stick using „dd“, exact command added to my question.

Comment: @Ramhound: Tried it with a 32bit Win.iso with same outcome. I managed to enter the BIOS boot menu for the first time by hacking my F10-key nearly to death, and the USB stick was not presented as a boot medium, regardless whether I put it into the front or rear ports.

Comment: I don't think the processor is the issue, but the method you used to create the USB: Your USB is probably not actually bootable. Please follow the instructions in the answers on this question on our sister site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312488/how-to-create-bootable-windows-10-image-in-debian

Comment: @music2myear you were right. I erroneously assumed, I could proceed as with disk images for any linux distro. I tried woeusb, which came with my distro (void linux) and it worked in an instant. Do you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DD` is useful for dealing with images, but does not create bootable drives.

For linux, `woeusb` is a recommended tool for creating bootable drives from image files:

```
sudo woeusb --device local/of/my/windows-10-image.iso /dev/sdX
```